# Is it possible to load more config files from an externalized config file in Grails?

Tags: grails, configuration, grails-config

Hypothetical situation:

I have downloaded a Grails application from the web as a WAR file, `foo.war`. In the documentation it says that I can put my own custom configuration in `/foo.groovy`, because this path is included in `grails.config.locations` in `Config.groovy`. I can dump all my custom config in that one file and life is good.

How, here's my problem... The configuration for FooApp is big and hairy, and I don't want it all in one file. I would like to break it up into `/bar.groovy` and `/baz.groovy` to keep things organized. Is there a way to specify something in `/foo.groovy` so that FooApp will also pick up `/bar.groovy` and `/baz.groovy` and process them?

I already tried appending paths to `grails.config.locations` in `/foo.groovy`, but Grails didn't like that and threw a nasty exception on startup. I'm not sure what other approach to take.

Edit for clarity:

`grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` looks like this:

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:/foo.groovy"]
```

Now, without modifying `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`, and only by modifying `/foo.groovy`, is there a way to load more config files other than `/foo.groovy`?

Comment: If this isn't possible, please consider raising this as a request in the [Grails Jira](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS).

Answer (score 2):

You could slurp the additional config files within `foo.groovy`:

**foo.groovy**

```
port {
  to {
    somewhere=8080
    another {
      place=7070
    }  
  }  
}
host = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("bar.groovy").toURL())
```

**bar.groovy**

```
to {
  somewhere="http://localhost/"
  another {
    place="https://another.place.com/"
  }
}
```

So within your app you have:

```
assert grailsApplication.config.port.to.somewhere == 8080
assert grailsApplication.config.port.to.another.place == 7070
assert grailsApplication.config.host.to.somewhere == "http://localhost/"
assert grailsApplication.config.host.to.another.place == "https://another.place.com/"
```